# Unexpected Plot output

Tags: plotting

I was trying to make a Plot of three functions, however, its output (below) is very different from what I expected.

[image]

There are two problems with this plot: first, it seems to be plotting just one function, as all three lines are of the same color. Second, the plot seems to be cut at around 1400.

My code is

```
p = {1/5, 1/4, 2/3};
v = {0, 6, 15};
u = 10;
eU = Table[p[[i]] Sqrt[wB] + (1 - p[[i]]) Sqrt[wM] - v[[i]], {i, 1, 3}];
Plot[Flatten[Table[wM /. Solve[eU[[i]] == u, {wM}], {i, 1, 3}]], {wB, 0, 1800}]
```

If, instead, I compute

```
Flatten[Table[wM /. Solve[eU[[i]] == u, {wM}], {i, 1, 3}]]
```

and paste the output into a `Plot` instruction

```
Plot[{1/16 (2500 - 100 Sqrt[wB] + wB), 1/9 (4096 - 128 Sqrt[wB] + wB),5625 - 300 Sqrt[wB] + 4 wB}, {wB, 900, 1500}]
```

I do get what I anticipated.

[image]

Comment: Try `Plot[Evaluate@Flatten[Table[wM /. Solve[eU[[i]] == u, {wM}], {i, 1, 3}]], {wB, 0,1800}]` as Plot has `HoldAll` attribute.

Comment: @Nasser, perfect, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

p = {1/5, 1/4, 2/3};
v = {0, 6, 15};
u = 10;
```

Because the basic operations are [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), the definition for `eU` can be written more simply as

```
eU = p*Sqrt[wB] + (1 - p)* Sqrt[wM] - v;
```

Because of the square roots, the solutions are conditional

```
wMval = SolveValues[# == u, wM, Reals] & /@ eU
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip[wMval]], {wB, 0, 1800}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.75, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Note that the third plot cuts off within the plot range (at `5625/4`, i.e., `1406.25`)

Alternatively, you could use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Thread[eU == 10], {wB, 0, 1800}, {wM, 0, 850},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.75, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Again note the cutoff of the third plot within the plot range.

Comment: I imagined there was a better way of defining eU. Very helpful. Also, very nice the conditional solutions, I was doing it by hand.